# How to prevent seeing overflow when highlighting text?

Tags: html, overflow

In the image below, my code is on the left and my output is on the right.  In the div, I allowed for y-overflow only, and set x-overflow to hidden, and replaced x-overflow with elipses.  As you can see, I was able to achieve this result in the output box.

However, If I click in the output box div and highlight the text say the "dddd..." part, and drag to the right, I can see all this empty space to the right of the elipses.  That is, I can highlight text and drag, to see the white-space overflow in the div.  Is there a way to prevent this from occuring?

[image]

Comment: You should really make a [***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/) about this, to allow people to bumble around and experiment to find a working solution for you. We don't really want to have to do this for you.

Comment: Just so you know, W3Schools isn't a very reliable source. Use it with caution. http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @jimjimmy1995, I was initially using my own website, but I used the w3 schools to illustrate the problem as it looks much simpler than my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I can "highlight" the text within the box and "drag" it to the right to see the "x-overflow" is because I was using the browser google chrome.  For some reason when I use the browser "firefox" the problem disappears.

(If anyone can suggest how to fix the problem in chrome please post an answer.)

Comment: Post an example of it on jsfiddle. It makes it so people can help.

Comment: `overflow:auto;` is user agent dependant, in chrome it defaults `text-wrap` to not wrapping, in firefox it was. Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Lc8Ru/15/

Comment: No I don't want the overflow text to wrap around.  I want the overflow text to be invisible, and inaccessible.  In my jsfiddle, the extra text was invisible at first, but unfortunately I could click and drag within the text box to see the extra text.  I didn't want this.

Comment: I solved the problem on my actual website, by using making the text an unordered list, and each line a list element.  Then the overflow was "truncated" and I could no longer access the extra text by click and dragging.  Not sure why this worked, but it did.